# Chrome Alarm events keeps firing every 4 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to pass a message triggered by an alarm from background.js to loader.js. Here is my code:

manifest.json:

```
{
"update_url": "https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx",

   "manifest_version": 2,
   "name": "DubX",
   "short_name": "DubX",
   "author": "Al3366",
   "description": "Automatically loads DubX on dubtrack.fm",
   "homepage_url": "https://dubx.net/",
   "version": "0",
   "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icons/48.png"
   },
   "permissions": ["background","alarms","tabs"],
   "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"],
      "persistent": false
    },
   "content_scripts": [{
      "matches": ["*://www.dubtrack.fm/*"],
      "js": ["jquery.js","loader.js"],
      "run_at": "document_end"
   }],

    "icons": { 
        "16": "icons/16.png",
        "19": "icons/19.png",
        "38": "icons/38.png",
        "48": "icons/48.png",
        "128": "icons/128.png" 
    }
}
```

background.js

```
chrome.alarms.create('hello',{delayInMinutes: 0.25});
chrome.alarms.onAlarm.addListener(function(alarm) {
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs){
        var content = {greeting: 'foo'};
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, content);  
    });
});
```

loader.js:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        if (request.greeting === 'foo') {
            hello();
        };
    }
);
$('body').prepend('<div class="cake" style=" z-index: 2147483647; color: white; position: fixed; bottom: 54px; left: 27px; background: #222; padding: 13px; -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75); -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75); box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75); border-radius: 5px;">Waiting for Dubtrack...</div>');
function hello() {
    $.getScript('https://rawgit.com/sinfulBA/DubX-Script/master/beta.js');
    $('.cake').remove();
};
```

It keeps firing the hello(); function every 4 seconds. I can't find out what I'm doing wrong. Thanks in advance for your reply.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're using [an event page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages) (non-persistent background page), which is unloaded after approximately 5 seconds of inactivity. Then some activity in the browser causes the background page to re-initialize and set a new alarm. So each 5 seconds that new alarm fires the handler that sends a message which makes the content script call `hello()`.

- Solution 1: check for some condition before invoking `chrome.alarms.create`.

  For example, if the real objective is to fire an alarm *one time* after the browser starts use [onStartup event](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onStartup) and set the alarm time with `when` key:

  ```
    chrome.runtime.onStartup.addListener(function() {
        chrome.alarms.create('hello', {when: Date.now() + 60*1000});
    });
  ```

  Note that in a published extension the interval between the next alarm and the last fired alarm is at least 1 minute even if you specify a smaller value like 15 seconds (15*1000).
- Solution 2 (a bad one): make the background page persistent by using `"persistent": true`. It's bad because a persistent background page hogs the memory. However, as explained in Xan's answer, it's a perfect one in case you actually need to fire the alarm each 15 seconds.

Comment: Ah, I didn't understand that it was a delay and not an interval.

Answer (score 2):

Please note: it's impossible to use `chrome.alarms` to do things with a granularity less than a minute.

Quoting [the docs](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/alarms#method-create):

> In order to reduce the load on the user's machine, Chrome limits alarms to at most once every 1 minute but may delay them an arbitrary amount more. That is, setting `delayInMinutes` or `periodInMinutes` to less than 1 will not be honored and will cause a warning.

So in a production environment, your alarm won't fire at all or will be delayed. You're observing the development environment effect:

> To help you debug your app or extension, when you've loaded it unpacked, there's no limit to how often the alarm can fire.

Despite wOxxOm's remark that a persistent background page is a "bad" solution, it's actually the *optimal* solution for tasks that require frequent repeated events. Reloading the event page every couple of minutes (or more frequently) is going to be a worse wastage of resources - event pages are for things that you know will not happen regularly or frequently.

<del>You should switch to a persistent background page and use good old [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval).</del>

Ah, sorry, I did not immediately understand that you had a *delay* and not an *interval*. Then wOxxOm's answer fully applies.

**UPDATE**
as of chrome 120, setting an alarm with less than 1 minute interval is possible. the docs says:

> Chrome 120: Starting in Chrome 120, the minimum alarm interval has been reduced from 1 minute to 30 seconds. For an alarm to trigger in 30 seconds, set periodInMinutes: 0.5.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to specify the alarm name for `onAlarm`.

```
chrome.alarms.create('hello', { periodInMinutes: 2.0 });

chrome.alarms.onAlarm.addListener(function(alarm) {

    if (alarm.name == 'hello') {
        // do your thing
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.